# Bind Data Model to UI Component - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-binding

Is there a way in Objective-C to bind a data model to a UI component?

Imagine a `UIViewController` which contains several `UITextField`s, each of which update a property in some object. Each `UITextField` could have a different object that it is updating.

When the update method for an individual `UITextField` is called, I'd like to be able to know which object that `UITextField` should update.

Anyone know how to do this, or if there is a design pattern that accomplishes this? Can you even bind a data model to a UI component in Objective-C?

Comment: When a textfield is editing, it's delegate method method get hit. You can use that delegate mthod to update your object. You can use tags to differentiate each textfield.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with that methodology, but I don't think it is good enough. If the UI is complex enough, which mine is, that can get quite complicated and unmaintainable very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This binding thing is from Xamarin methodology i think. XCode does not have such thing. You need to use the delegates.

In your case, for multiple textfields created either in storyboard/xib or programatically, you need to apply its delegate and set the textfields "tag" property. Then in the delegate, you can handle each textfields using its unique tags. It is quite simple.